# mailto using variable missing out subject

Tags: php, html, variables, mailto, subject

I'm looking to those with far more experienced than me for a solution to a problem.

The following works partly.

```
echo "<td width='28%'>" .
    $qry['name'] .
    "<br>" .
    $qry['address1'] .
    "<br>" .
    $qry['address2'] .
    "<br>" .
    $qry['town'] .
    "<br>" .
    $qry['postcode'] .
    "<br>TeleNo : " .
    $qry['telephone'] .
    "<br>" .
    $qry['email'] .
    "<a href='mailto:" .
    $qry['email'] .
    "'?Subject=Thank%20You>  - Send eMail</a></td>";
```

It creates the table field OK and, when "Send eMail" is clicked, the email client pops up opening an email with the address in the To field OK but the Subject field is blank.

I've tried all combinations of single and double quotation marks but some fail while no working combination will fill the subject field in the email.

I could live with that but I'd really prefer it worked.

Any suggestions gratefully received.

Comment: Just hit "Ctrl+U" (or your browser's short-cut for "View Source") and look at the **generated** HTML.

Comment: Do you need help? Soplease  post your code here and not just a small snippet. Nobody here wants to guess.

Comment: There's no need to guess - all the information you needed to solve the problem was in the snippet. Thanks to Muhammet for using his eyes!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look at the closing quote, it should be after subject:

```
<a href='mailto:" . $qry['email'] . "?Subject=Thank%20You'>
```

NOT

```
<a href='mailto:" . $qry['email'] . "'?Subject=Thank%20You>
```

Comment: Please let me insist: it's several orders of magnitude easier to spot invalid HTML in the HTML itself, rather than the PHP used to generate it.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález Correct.